# PHP's MD5 in filename, but cannot open file ... receiving errors

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am trying to download images with wget, and I am renaming each image with PHP's md5 function for uniqueness (a bit overkill as I think). The script is 
working well and saving the new image name (hastag) in a MySQL db. The problem is when I am trying to retrieve these images from a directory, I am receiving errors "failed to open stream: No such file or directory." I have cross-checked everything all files and image path are alright. The notable thing is that as I rename a downloaded image to something very simple (i.e. the hastag in filename is very long) my script finds that image and its path.

Here is how I download and rename images

```
$output = "/cygdrive/e/images/" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . ".jpg";
$cmd = "wget -nc --tries=3 -T30 --restrict-file-names=nocontrol -q \"$url\" -O $output";
echo "Please wait ... fetching image from the URL:" . $url . PHP_EOL; 
$result = exec($cmd, $array, $return);
```

Now, for example, I have four images saved in `images` folder

```
images/1c1568db43220557b8b95326552825e6.jpg
images/2e0cf05f73201c1f3ff85fa6c5290a52.jpg
images/eca425148fe2ac9de939e57d79a73e45.jpg
images/16b15fcb9c58bf31c7f29fc7bdcf7a26.jpg
```

and, I am retrieving them as such (below). the retrieval part works well, but if I try to further process that image, for example, calling via a GD function, the error "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" occurs. However, when I rename those images to, for example, boy.jpg, girl.jpg, man.jpg or women.jpg, it works.

```
#############
# DB settings  #
#############

include_once('../includes/connection.inc.php');
// create database connection
$conn = dbConnect('write');
$numRows = FALSE;
$i = 14; 
//prepare SQL query
$sql = "SELECT name FROM imgname WHERE image_id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($sql))
{
    // bind the query parameter
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $i);
    // execute the query, and fetch the result
    $stmt->execute();
    // bind the results to variables
    $stmt->bind_result($name);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $numRows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->fetch();
    // free the database resources for the second query
    $stmt->free_result();

} else {
    $error = $stmt->error;
} 

if ($numRows) {
    echo "images/" . $name;     

} else {
    echo "could not fetch an row";
}
```

Here is my database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `imgname` (
  `image_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `keyword_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(2083) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8255 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `imgname`
--

INSERT INTO `imgname` (`image_id`, `keyword_id`, `url`, `name`, `size`, `color`, `type`, `created_at`) VALUES
(9, 983, 'https://migrainetime.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/dscn2467.jpg', '2fb8aa38d26509df122c685b91398608.jpg', 'islt:4mp', 'ic:color', 'itp:face', '2015-08-11 23:01:53'),
(10, 1323, 'https://i1.wp.com/thenypost.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/i_ll_see_you_in_my_dreams.jpg', '9142c1b3379036eb813e5aaecbe0c80e.jpg', 'islt:4mp', 'ic:color', 'itp:face', '2015-08-11 23:04:00'),
(11, 417, 'http://redandhoney.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/dsc_0124.jpg', '5ea2e5e667d120bcdd34906b80e1a6f3.jpg', 'islt:4mp', 'ic:color', 'itp:face', '2015-08-11 23:16:57'),
(12, 5, 'http://images.lifeandstylemag.com/uploads/posts/image/53883/melissa-mccarthy-weight-loss.jpg', '2b777af57276a0e46ae27fba43f02b49.jpg', '4mp', 'color', 'face', '2015-08-12 00:16:56'),
(13, 5, 'http://images.lifeandstylemag.com/uploads/posts/image/53883/melissa-mccarthy-weight-loss.jpg', 'de9f1ddd75c25e4c2f7378825ed5e30c.jpg', '4mp', 'color', 'face', '2015-08-12 00:17:36'),
```

Comment: you don't seem to be storing that md5 hash in your db. what exactly is in this `name` field?

Comment: also, you seem to open the db connection for 'write'?

Comment: @Marc B, you seems to be right. It is the case. I am double checking again, however.

Comment: So as i understand it you have narrowed it down to being the filename length so far ?